# Issue Splitting in Python

Tags: python

The goal is to  get the text after '%' and before '--'.

However sometimes text is being cut off before '--', like at a random letter. Why is this not working properly? Thank you in advance! PS using Python 3.5.

```
if destiny=='fortune':
    fortuneformat= fortune_print.split('%')[-1]
     print (fortuneformat)
    _1_fortuneformat= fortuneformat.split("--")[0]

    fortunesay = str(_1_fortuneformat)
```

FYI:

```
fortune_print= get_random_fortune('quotes1.txt')
```

And here is the function used to get a fortune.

```
def get_random_fortune(fortune_file):
    """
    Get a random fortune from the specified file. Barfs if the corresponding
    ``.dat`` file isn't present.byt
    :Parameters:
        fortune_file : str
            path to file containing fortune cookies
    :rtype:  str
    :return: the random fortune
    """
    fortune_index_file = fortune_file + '.dat'
    if not os.path.exists(fortune_index_file):
        print( 'Can\'t find file "%s"' % fortune_index_file)

    fortuneIndex = open(fortune_index_file, 'rb')
    data = pickle.load(fortuneIndex)
    fortuneIndex.close()
    randomRecord = random_int(0, len(data) - 1)
    (start, length) = data[randomRecord]

    f = open(fortune_file, 'rU')
    f.seek(start)
    fortuneCookie = f.read(length)
    f.close()
    return fortuneCookie
```

Example input of a fortune from the text file that is providing input:

```
%
The NSA knows what you did last summer. But no one, in the NSA or outside it,
knows why they should.

    -- Shlomi Fish
    -- NSA Facts by Shlomi Fish and Friends ( http://www.shlomifish.org/humour/bits/facts/NSA/ )
```

Expected output: `The NSA knows what you did last summer. But no one, in the NSA or outside it, knows why they should.`

Actual output: `The NSA knows what yo`

I have been asked how the pickled file is made. It is done with pickle.dump in this function:

```
def make_fortune_data_file(fortune_file, quiet=False):
    """
    Create or update the data file for a fortune cookie file.
    :Parameters:
        fortune_file : str
            path to file containing fortune cookies
        quiet : bool
            If ``True``, don't display progress messages
    """
    fortune_index_file = fortune_file + '.dat'
    if not quiet:
        pass
        #print ('Updating "%s" from "%s"...' % (fortune_index_file, fortune_file))

    data = []
    shortest = sys.maxsize
    longest = 0
    for start, length, fortune in _read_fortunes(open(fortune_file, 'rU')):
        data += [(start, length)]
        shortest = min(shortest, length)
        longest = max(longest, length)

    fortuneIndex = open(fortune_index_file,'wb')
    pickle.dump(data, fortuneIndex,protocol=4,fix_imports=True)
    fortuneIndex.close()
```

Comment: can you posted sample sample input, and expected output vs actual output?

Comment: Code looks fine at a glance. Post a [mcve].

Comment: Hi I added the sample input, and expected output vs actual output. I hope this makes my post easier to analyze. Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you sure `fortune_print` contains what you think it does? How did you create the pickled file?

Comment: @Holloway I am new to pickle, just FYI. I have updated the code to include how the pickled file is made. See bottom of the original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use regex to find the fortunes instead?

```
s = """%
The NSA knows what you did last summer. But no one, in the NSA or outside it,
knows why they should.

    -- Shlom%i Fish
    -- NSA Facts by Shlomi Fish and Friends 
( http://www.shlomifish.org/humour/bits/facts/NSA/ )
% XSLT is the worst thing since non-sliced bread. -- Shlomi Fish -- 
XSLT Facts by Shlomi Fish and Friends ("""

re.findall("(?s)(?<=%).*?(?=--)",s)


Out[154]:
['\nThe NSA knows what you did last summer. But no one, in the NSA or outside it,\nknows why they should.\n\n    ',
 'i Fish\n    ',
 ' XSLT is the worst thing since non-sliced bread. ']
```

https://regex101.com/r/dQ9bD3/1

Comment: Thanks! This works for some but not all. For instance - original fortune text: %
XSLT is the worst thing since non-sliced bread.

    -- Shlomi Fish
    -- XSLT Facts by Shlomi Fish and Friends ( http://www.shlomifish.org/humour/bits/facts/XSLT/ )
%                                                                                                                Output from regex: []

Comment: Output before regex applied (by using print (fortune_print)):  mmer Glau Facts by Shlomi Fish and Friends ( http://www.shlomifish.org/humour/bits/facts/Summer-Glau/ )
%
XSLT is the worst thing since non-sliced bread.

    -- Shlomi Fish
    -- X

Comment: @stuffatwork190 Please do not add code or line-separated output via comments. As you can see, the formatting does not make sense.

Comment: Regex is updated - should work for all examples now.